# Setting chekbox value to struts form when it's unchekd

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, struts-1

I have a jsp which contain a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="coursForm.blocagevl" value="${atelierUCForm.coursForm.blocagevl}" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0)"/>
```

Which gets its value from database and currently it's getting 1 in the example I am giving above.
When I am submitting this form it's setting 1 in the struts action form when the checkbox is checked but when I am unchecking it the value attribute of chekbox is changed to 0 due to the onclick event of chekbox but again after submitting it 1 is going to the action form instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you overriding the `reset()` method in `ActionForm`. If not declare the reset method and initiate/set the values as empty/null.

```
public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, 
    HttpServletRequest request) {

 //Initializing the properties
 blocagevl = null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome, Mark as answer. Might be useful to someone.